# HtmlAgilityPack fails to detect unbalanced divs between <html> and </html>

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

It seems like htmlagility fails to detect html inbalance where a div is not closed and the `</html>` end tag comes. Like every sin is forgotten.

Why?

Here is a test that fails:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace Foo.Tests.LibraryTests    
{
  [TestClass]
  public class HtmlAgilityPackTest
  {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestUnbalancedStartTag()
    {
      var html = "<html><div></html>";

      AssertErrorCount(html, 1);
    }

    private void AssertErrorCount(string html, int expectedNumErrors)
    {
      var doc = Load(html);
      Assert.AreEqual(expectedNumErrors, doc.ParseErrors.Count());
    }

    private HtmlDocument Load(string html)
    {
      var doc = new HtmlDocument
      {
        OptionFixNestedTags = false,
        OptionCheckSyntax = true,
        OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = false
      };

      doc.Load(new StringReader(html));

      return doc;
    }
  }
}
```

I expect an error, but there isnt one.

If the line

```
      var html = "<html><div></html>";
```

is changed to

```
      var html = "<div><div></div>";
```

the test succeeds (html agility will correctly report a parse error).

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers handle this the same way: The closing `</html>` tag also closes all other open elements. And as it is says on the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) page:

> "The parser is very tolerant with 'real world' malformed HTML".

Comment: And there is no way of making it intolerant then?

Comment: None that I know of.

Comment: The fact that htmlagilitypack is intolerant with `<div><div></div>` makes me want to have this question open a bit longer.